# Trying to understand concatenating number variables with a string

Tags: python, variables

Just confused as to why one of these code snippets work, and the other dosen't.

The first one that works is:

```
x = 1
y = 1
a = x + y
(print("Ipsum: " + str(a)))
```

So I essentially just want to add x and y without creating a variable to store their values, if this can even be done. So I don't understand why the below code does not work:

```
x = 1
y = 1
(print("Ipsum: " + str(x) + str(y)))
```

Comment: You want `"Ipsum" + str(x + y)`…?

Comment: @deceze yes that's what I was looking for thanks, new to programming still learning the kinks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are concatenating two strings where what you really want is this:

```
x = 1
y = 1
print("Ipsum: " + str(x+y))
```

Even better, use an f-string thus:

```
x = 1
y = 1
print(f'Ipsum: {x+y}')
```

**Output (same for both examples):**

```
Ipsum: 2
```

Comment: For completeness: `print('Ipsum:', x + y)`.

Comment: @deceze Of course you're correct. However, I have a personal aversion to passing multiple parameters to *print()*

Comment: Personally I *prefer* it a lot, since it's usually more readable, *and* it's more efficient then having to do some type juggling or concatenation *and then* printing.

Comment: How come this does not work:  `x=input("What is x? ")
y=input("Now what is y? ")
print("Here's your result: " + str(x)+ str(y))`

Comment: That code is essentially the same as your second snippet and that didn't work.

Comment: @quamrana is there a way I could make this work without using an f-string?

Comment: Well, yes. Use the first snippet in this answer. You will, of course, need to convert x and y to into int first.

Comment: @quamrana Ah I think I've got it, so it would be `x = 1
y = 1
x=input("What is x? ")
y=input("Now what is y? ")
print("Here's your result: " + str(int(x)+int(y)))`

Comment: Ok, that works, but you don't need 'x=1; y=1', just the rest.